# How to format unsigned int into 8 digit hexadecimal number?

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I want to format an unsigned int to an 8 digit long string with leading zeroes.

This is what I have so far:

```
  unsigned int number = 260291273;
  char output[9];
  sprintf(output, "%x", number);
  printf("%s\n", output); // or write it into a file with fputs
```

Prints "f83bac9", but I want "0f83bac9". How can I achieve the formatting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I could imagine that it be for a question that can be simply answered by looking into the manual page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use "%08x" as your format string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use zero-padding by specifying `0` and the number of digits you want, between `%` and the format type.

For instance, for hexadecimal numbers with (at least) 8 digits, you'd use `%08x`:

```
printf("%08x", number);
```

Output (if `number` is 500):

> 000001f4